# Is it possible to change the database in Bitnami MEAN stack in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, mean-stack, bitnami, google-cloud-launcher

I want to use ElasticSearch instead of MongoDB. How can I achieve this?
Is there a way to install everything from scratch and configure it? Configuration is the challenging part. I'm looking for tutorials explaining how to replace MongoDB with Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1):

There's not an easy way to substitute MongoDB with Elasticsearch on the stack.

However, you can easily install a Bitnami Elasticsearch stack (https://bitnami.com/stack/elasticsearch) on a different directory. For instance, if you have your MEAN stack on the default directory (/opt/bitnami/), you can install the Elasticsearch stack at `/opt/elasticsearch/` and then edit the environment/control scripts of the original stack so you disable MongoDB and add the ability to control Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have everything in the same VM, then I advise you to use our Elasticsearch installer: https://bitnami.com/stack/elasticsearch/installer

This way you would have your MEAN stack and, in addition, an Elasticsearch stack. Then you can disable MongoDB if you don't plan to use it at all.

sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh stop mongodb

sudo mv /opt/bitnami/mongodb/scripts/ctl.sh

sudo /opt/bitnami/mongodb/scripts/ctl.sh.disabled

Credits - 
jsalmeron - bitnami